# Adding SCA on Stripe gateway

Tags: stripe-payments, gateway

I have an application and using Stripe Noback-end API for handling payments like this:

```
stripe.tokens.create({
    card: {
        "number": request.full_card_number,
        "exp_month": request.exp_month,
        "exp_year": request.exp_year,
        "cvc": request.cvc
    }
}, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
        resp.json(err)
    } else {
        stripe.charges.create({
            amount: request.amount,
            currency: request.currency,
            source: token.id,
            description: request.description,
            capture: true
        }, function(err, charge) {
            if (err) {
                resp.json(err)
            } else {
                resp.json(charge)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This will handle the payments really cool by back-end codes. But now we should add SCA to our apps. How can I add SCA and verify step on gateway and still using back-end API on my app?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration/automatic-confirmation

Comment: @PaulAsjes  this doc says I should load an Iframe box to show verification step to customer by srtipe.js. Is there any way that we can show our verification box and ask verification code from customer and send it to stripe back-end? I mean not loading stripe Iframe or stripe.js. Handeling it by own code and only communicate in back-end ?

Comment: You can customize the 3DS iframe and not use Stripe.js, but you always need  a frontend to show the 3DS page: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure-iframe